# HLSL and Pix number of questions

Tags: xna, hlsl, pixel-shader

I'm having a number of isses with HLSL and Pix.

1) Can you in HLSL 3, declare a Pixel shader alone without a Vertex Shader? If not, what can I do to get around this?

2) Why does Pix skip code? I have a reasonably long shader method but Pix seems to stop me from debugging until half way through the method and then skips the rest of the block. I set Pix to gather information when F12 is hit and check the DISABLE D3DX analysis checkbox. I have to do this because I'm using XNA.

3) Can I debug the shader as the experiment is being run?

Cheers,

Comment: Can you split this into several questions, and add a bit more detail?

Comment: @AndrewRussell Ok I've done that. I've split them here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773640/hlsl-3-can-a-pixel-shader-be-declared-alone and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774438/pix-a-couple-of-issues-im-not-understanding