# Pix, A couple of issues I'm not understanding

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl

I've been asked to split questions which I asked here:

[HLSL and Pix number of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763278/hlsl-and-pix-number-of-questions)

I thought two and three would both fit in the same question as a solution of one may help resolve the other. I'm trying to debug a shader and seem to be running into issues. Firstly Pix seems to be skipping a large amount of code when I'm running analyse mode. This is analysing an experiment with F12 captures and with D3DX analysis turned off. I have to turn it off as I'm using XNA. The shader code in question is below:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 OriginalUV : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{   

    // Get the depth buffer value at this pixel.  
    float4 color = float4 (0, 0,0,0);
    float4 finalColor = float4(0,0,0,0);

    float zOverW = tex2D(mySampler, OriginalUV);  
    // H is the viewport position at this pixel in the range -1 to 1.  
    float4 H = float4(OriginalUV.x * 2 - 1, (1 - OriginalUV.y) * 2 - 1,  
    zOverW, 1);  
    // Transform by the view-projection inverse.  
    float4 D = mul(H, xViewProjectionInverseMatrix);  
    // Divide by w to get the world position.  
    float4 worldPos = D / D.w;  

    // Current viewport position  
    float4 currentPos = H;  
    // Use the world position, and transform by the previous view-  
    // projection matrix.  
    float4 previousPos = mul(worldPos, xPreviousViewProjectionMatrix);  
    // Convert to nonhomogeneous points [-1,1] by dividing by w.  
    previousPos /= previousPos.w;  
    // Use this frame's position and last frame's to compute the pixel  
       // velocity.  
    float2 velocity = (currentPos - previousPos)/2.f;  

    // Get the initial color at this pixel.  
    color = tex2D(sceneSampler, OriginalUV);  
    OriginalUV += velocity;  
    for(int i = 1; i < 1; ++i, OriginalUV += velocity)  
    {  
        // Sample the color buffer along the velocity vector.  
        float4 currentColor = tex2D(sceneSampler, OriginalUV);  
        // Add the current color to our color sum.  
        color += currentColor;  
    } 
    // Average all of the samples to get the final blur color.  
    finalColor = color / xNumSamples;  


    return finalColor;
}
```

With a captured frame and when debugging a pixel I can only see two lines working. These are color = tex2D(sceneSampler, OriginalUV) and finalColor = color / xNumSamples. The rest of it Pix just skips or doesn't do.

Also can I debug in real time using Pix? I'm wondering if this method would reveal more information.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that most of that shader code is being optimized out (not compiled because it is irrelevant).

In the end, all that matters in the return value of `finalColor` which is set with `color` and `xNumSamples`.

```
// Average all of the samples to get the final blur color.  
finalColor = color / xNumSamples;
```

I am not sure where `xNumSamples` gets set, but you can see that the only line that matters to `color` is `color = tex2D(sceneSampler, OriginalUV);` (hence it not being removed).

Every line before that is irrelevant because it will be overwritten by that line.

The only bit that follows is that for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 1; ++i, OriginalUV += velocity)
```

But this would never execute because `i < 1` is false from the get-go (i is assigned a starting value of 1).

Hope that helps!

---

To answer you second question, I believe to debug shaders in real-time you need to use something like Nvidia's [FX Composer](https://developer.nvidia.com/fx-composer) and [Shader Debugger](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-shader-debugger). However, those run outside of your game, so results are not always useful.

Comment: Ok, I think that for loop line was me fiddling with things so that's me forgetting to switch values back. I'm basically trying to achieve the motion blur effect found here: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch27.html I've tried to copy this methodology as much as possible but I'm concerned if the compiler is optimizing it out that this methodology is impossible.

Comment: After fixing the loop it should not remove the lines above; it uses that data in the loop. Are you still having issues after fixing the loop?

Comment: Ahh, ok you're correct, I seem to be getting some sort of effect now so can probably work it out from there. Cheers